# RedirectToPagePreserveMethod Redirects but doesn’t preserve method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to use RedirectToPagePreserveMethod, and the page does get redirected, but it’s not preserving the method. I am calling it on a Post and the redirect is a Get.

I inspected the RedirectToPage result, and the PreserveMethod is true, I am redirecting to a page in the root of the Page directory. The destination page doesn’t have any routing parameters and has the IgnoreAntiForgeryToken attribute.

What would cause it to fail in this manner?

```cs
 var r = RedirectToPagePreserveMethod(“/CloseMyWindow”, null, null);
 return r;
```

I've tried adding a page handler "Post" to the redirect, but that didn't help.

The function returns a `Task<IActionResult>` and the destination page has

```cs
@page
@model Ns.Website.CloseMyWindowModel
@{
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code sample?

Comment: @YiyiYou: added the redirect code, but it’s just as described.